# Turn off "smooth line art" rendering feature in MuPDF

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

I develop an e-book reader for Android and I'm using MuPDF library. I have some e-magazines that are PDF/X-1 standard compatible, which is unfortunately not fully compatible with transparency features, therefore when you would open a digital magazine you would see lines that should not be there, although they would not be visible when the magazine is printed. More about this problem can be found at this forum: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/285775.

However, in Acrobat Reader there is an option to turn off the "smooth line art" rendering feature and then these lines are not visible anymore. Can be something similar done in the MuPDF library (there is umpteen amount of source code and I wasn't able to find it)? Or have anyone had similar problem and successfuly resolved it in any library that can be used on Android? I would like to find solution at the application level, editing PDF documents into the compatible format is not much desirable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

-b0 should turn off anti-aliasing.

Comment: HOw do you send this param?

Comment: I wasn't clear from this question that this was a command-line situation

Comment: If its not a command line problem, then you can look at the source for Mudraw or MuPDF and see what it does in response to those command line switches.

Comment: It's not command line problem. I'll take a look on it, thanks for the answer.